# NodeJS + Graphql: How can I run code even after sending a response?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have an endpoint that receives files and creates a background task for uploading those files to S3.

In order to background the file uploads, I'm using Agenda (https://github.com/agenda/agenda). The only limitation is that I need to store the file in a format that is supported by MongoDB (which is what Agenda uses under the hood). In order to do that, I am converting the file as a buffer before sending that over to Agenda.

This is my code:

```
  Mutation: {
    batchCreateProgressPics: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, { pics }, { models, currentUser }) => {
        return await Promise.all(
          pics.map(async (pic, i) => {
            const { file, bodyPart, localPath } = pic;
            const { createReadStream } = await file;
            const stream = createReadStream();

            console.log("Setting up buffer...");
            const buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              var buffers = [];
              stream.on("data", function(data) {
                buffers.push(data);
              });
              stream.on("end", function() {
                const everything = Buffer.concat(buffers);
                resolve(everything);
              });
              stream.on("error", function(e) {
                reject(e);
              });
            });

            const progressPic = await models.ProgressPic.create({
              bodyPart,
              user: currentUser.id,
              url: localPath,
            });

            console.log("Creating backgruond task...");
            Agenda.now("uploadProgressPic", {
              userId: currentUser.id,
              progressPicId: progressPic.id,
              filename: `${progressPic.id}-${bodyPart}.jpg`,
              buffer,
            });
            console.log("Done.");

            return progressPic;
          })
        );
      }
    ),
  },
```

This is fast on my local development server, but taking a long time to run in production because of the buffer stuff. The lines following `console.log(Setting up buffer...)` are taking a long time.

What I would like to do is:

1. Create and return an array of progressPics, one for each element in the `pics` array
2. Do the buffer stuff after the response has been sent so it doesn't hold up the front end.

Is this possible?

============ UPDATE ==========

So if I do not `await` for the promise, it complains that the request disconnected before the buffer finished:

```
const uploadProgressPic = async ({ file, progressPicId, userId, bodyPart }) => {
  try {
    const { createReadStream } = await file;
    const stream = createReadStream();

    console.log("Setting up buffer...");
    const buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var buffers = [];
      stream.on("data", function(data) {
        buffers.push(data);
      });
      stream.on("end", function() {
        const everything = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        resolve(everything);
      });
      stream.on("error", function(e) {
        reject(e);
      });
    });
    console.log("Done.");

    console.log("Creating backgruond task...");
    Agenda.now("uploadProgressPic", {
      userId,
      progressPicId,
      filename: `${progressPicId}-${bodyPart}.jpg`,
      buffer,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR OCCURRED: ", error);
  }
};

export default {
  Mutation: {
    batchCreateProgressPics: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, { pics }, { models, currentUser }) => {
        return pics.map(async (pic, i) => {
          const { file, bodyPart, localPath } = pic;
          const progressPic = await models.ProgressPic.create({
            bodyPart,
            user: currentUser.id,
            url: localPath,
          });

          uploadProgressPic({
            file,
            progressPicId: progressPic.id,
            userId: currentUser.id,
            bodyPart,
          });

          return progressPic;
        });
      }
    ),
  },
};
```

Error:

```
ERROR OCCURRED:  BadRequestError: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/acne-tracker/server/node_modules/graphql-upload/lib/processRequest.js:300:35)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at resOnFinish (_http_server.js:614:7)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:649:10)
    at onCorkedFinish (_stream_writable.js:678:5)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:483:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  message: 'Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.',
  expose: true,
  statusCode: 499,
  status: 499
}
```

========== UPDATE 2 =============

Even trying to 1) simplify it and 2) move `createReadStream()` outside of `uploadProgressPic` shows the same error:

```
const uploadProgressPic = async ({
  stream,
  progressPicId,
  userId,
  bodyPart,
  models,
}) => {
  try {
    console.log("Uploading to S3...");
    const { Location: url, Key: key, Bucket: bucket } = await S3.upload({
      stream,
      folder: userId,
      filename: `${progressPicId}-${bodyPart}.jpg`,
    });

    if (url && key && bucket) {
      await models.ProgressPic.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: progressPicId },
        { $set: { url, key, bucket } },
        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
      );
      console.log("Done!");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR OCCURRED: ", error);
  }
};

export default {
  Mutation: {
    batchCreateProgressPics: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, { pics }, { models, currentUser }) => {
        return pics.map(async (pic, i) => {
          const { file, bodyPart, localPath } = pic;
          const progressPic = await models.ProgressPic.create({
            bodyPart,
            user: currentUser.id,
            url: localPath,
          });

          const { createReadStream } = await file;
          const stream = createReadStream();

          uploadProgressPic({
            stream,
            progressPicId: progressPic.id,
            userId: currentUser.id,
            bodyPart,
            models,
          });

          return progressPic;
        });
      }
    ),
  },
};
```

Error:

```
Uploading to S3...
Uploading to S3...
Uploading to S3...
ERROR OCCURRED:  BadRequestError: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/acne-tracker/server/node_modules/graphql-upload/lib/processRequest.js:300:35)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at resOnFinish (_http_server.js:614:7)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:208:15)
    at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:471:20)
    at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:649:10)
    at onCorkedFinish (_stream_writable.js:678:5)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:483:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
  message: 'Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.',
  expose: true,
  statusCode: 499,
  status: 499
}
Done!
```

Funny thing is I still see a few `Done!`s in the logs even though it complains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a variety of things that ended up not working because creating the buffer was just too slow in production for some reason. My ultimate solution that actually works was to split up the upload into two requests:

Backend:

Request #1: Create a progress pic, using the local file path as the URL
Request #2: Upload the file and update the progress pic

```
import { combineResolvers } from "graphql-resolvers";
import { isAuthenticated } from "./authorization";

import S3 from "../services/s3";

export default {
  Query: {
    progressPics: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, args, { models, currentUser }) => {
        return await models.ProgressPic.find({ user: currentUser.id });
      }
    ),
  },
  Mutation: {
    createProgressPics: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, { pics }, { models, currentUser }) => {
        return pics.map(async (pic, i) => {
          const { bodyPart, localPath } = pic;
          return await models.ProgressPic.create({
            bodyPart,
            user: currentUser.id,
            url: localPath,
          });

          return progressPic;
        });
      }
    ),
    updateProgressPics: combineResolvers(
      isAuthenticated,
      async (parent, { pics }, { models, currentUser }) => {
        return pics.map(async (pic, i) => {
          const { file, filename, progressPicId } = pic;
          const { createReadStream } = await file;
          const stream = createReadStream();

          const { Location: url, Key: key, Bucket: bucket } = await S3.upload({
            stream,
            filename,
            folder: currentUser.id,
          });

          return await models.ProgressPic.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: progressPicId },
            { $set: { url, key, bucket } },
            { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
          );
        });
      }
    ),
  },
};
```

The frontend will then wait for the response from Request #1, and send Request #2 but ignore the response so it can just return immediately.

```
  const createAndUploadProgressPics = async photos => {
    const {
      data: { createProgressPics: progressPics },
    } = await createProgressPics({
      variables: {
        pics: photos.map((p, i) => ({
          bodyPart: BODY_PARTS[i],
          localPath: p.uri,
        })),
      },
    });

    updateProgressPics({
      variables: {
        pics: progressPics.map(({ id, bodyPart }, i) => {
          return {
            progressPicId: id,
            filename: `${id}-${bodyPart}.jpg`,
            file: photos[i],
          };
        }),
      },
    });

    onFinish(progressPics);
    navigation.goBack();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't await the Promise.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var buffers = [];
  stream.on("data", function(data) {
    buffers.push(data);
  });
  stream.on("end", function() {
    const everything = Buffer.concat(buffers);
    resolve(everything);
  });
  stream.on("error", function(e) {
    reject(e);
  });
}).then((buffer) => {
  Agenda.now("uploadProgressPic", {
    userId: currentUser.id,
    progressPicId: progressPic.id,
    filename: `${progressPic.id}-${bodyPart}.jpg`,
    buffer,
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  // Clean up here
});

return models.ProgressPic.create({
  bodyPart,
  user: currentUser.id,
  url: localPath,
});
```

This way, you'll kick off creating the buffers, but won't actually wait for that to code to execute and will immediately create the ProgressPic instance and return it. Because the call to `Agenda.now` requires the resolved value of the Promise, we stick it inside the `then` callback. Note that it's important to append a `catch` as well -- if you don't, you could end up with an unhandled rejection.

You may want to use the `catch` callback to log the error and do any additional cleanup. For example, you may want to create the created ProgressPic (in which case, you should move the `create` call above the buffer Promise so you can reference the created instance).

If you're like me and die a little bit on the inside each time you have to type `then`, you can extract all that logic into a separate function:

```
const uploadProgressPic = async (/* parameters omitted for brevity */) => {
  try {
    const buffer = await new Promise(...)
    Agenda.now(...)
  } catch (error) {
    // Do whatever
  }
}
```

and then call it inside your resolver, again, **without** awaiting it:

```
uploadProgressPic()

return models.ProgressPic.create({
  bodyPart,
  user: currentUser.id,
  url: localPath,
});
```

Comment: I'll try this out! Will execution of the code within the non-awaited promise continue to execute even after the response is sent?

Comment: So it looks like it does disconnect: ERROR OCCURRED:  BadRequestError: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/acne-tracker/server/node_modules/graphql-upload/lib/processRequest.js:300:35)

Comment: Hmm that's problematic. Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload), the following is called out: "Only use createReadStream() before the resolver returns; late calls (e.g. in an unawaited async function or callback) throw an error. Existing streams can still be used after a response is sent, although there are few valid reasons for not awaiting their completion."

Comment: @bigpotato I would try moving the `await file` and `createReadStream()` lines outside of the `uploadProgressPic` function and just passing the stream to the function instead.

Comment: I tried it but it still shows an error. Updated the question

Comment: Crud. Returning an array of Promises *should* be the same as using Promise.all, but you could also try wrapping the `map` in `Promise.all` and seeing if that makes a difference: `return Promise.all(pics.map(async (pic, i) => {`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199985/discussion-between-daniel-rearden-and-bigpotato).

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on the subject but i have an idea that may work and a theory :

- **IDEA**: if you're dealing with a big number a images than your problem may originate from the await Promise.all(). i recommend that you use [parallelLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallelLimit) from async to limit the parallel functions to be executed at a time otherwise you will have a performance problem.
- **THEORY**: Maybe you can free the memory allocation after each use of `Buffer` to avoid memory leak problems and make your server more performant.

If i am wrong in anyway please correct me. I myself interested in the outcome of this problem.